# Executing a none existing hook in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there any reason to why, in my case a plugin, to have a `do_action();` to a none existing hook/action?

Example from WooCommerce, writepanel-product-data.php:

```
do_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku');
```

If I search after `woocommerce_product_options_sku` I cannot find it. So it just a call for a hook that doesn't exist, but why?

*I have seen this multiple times. But have no idea why one does this. Perhaps someone could enlighten me?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This way you can interact with woocommerce plugin without the need of modificate the source code of the plugin.

That is, woocommerce plugin programmers have considered that the developers may need some extra options, so you can program a plugin that uses add_action('woocommerce_product_options_sku', 'your_function'); and that will be called just at the point where do_action ('woocommerce_product_options_sku') was inserted.

If you need more information:

- http://wp.smashingmagazine.com/2011/10/07/definitive-guide-wordpress-hooks/
- http://wcdocs.woothemes.com/codex/extending/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/

Comment: But this only allows me to add, not edit or removing existing options/functions?

Comment: This hook does not pass arguments to the function, so I think you can only add options, but I don't use woocommerce plugin, I only explain hook mechanism in Wordpress.